# SOQL Can't create USERS relationship?

Tags: soql

I think what I'm trying to do is pretty simple.  I simply want a list of accounts, but have information like the account owner displayed.  I know the ACCOUNT table has "OwnerID", which joins with "ID" in USER, but for some reason I can't get it to link with this SOQL query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name from USERS) 
 FROM Account 
 WHERE OwnerId IN 
(SELECT Id FROM USER WHERE Name = 'John Doe') LIMIT 10
```

I get the following error:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name from USER) 
                                   ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:36
Didn't understand relationship 'USER' in FROM part of query call. If you are
attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the
custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for
the appropriate names.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

`select id, name, owner.name from Account where ...`

You cannot use a subquery like `SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name from USERS)` because `USERS` does not match any relationship field on the `Account` SObject.

Comment: This works!! obviously I missed an important lesson somewhere.. What just happened?